Spanner JDBC Driver option to avoid latency
We are using the google spanner jdbc driver(google-cloud-spanner-jdbc) to enable connectivity from our application to cloud spanner. This was used instead of the google client libraries to reuse the existing code and framework which used jdbctemplate based data access. We have a multi region environment for applicaiton deployment . All looks ok until we see latency issues for connecting to spanner from one region. All write operations have a higher latency from the non primary region while its much lesser when calls to go the primary leade spanner.
Google documentation mentions to use "enableLeaderAwareRouting" to resolve this  ,but that seems to be available only with google client libraries.
Do we have the same or equivalent configuration in the spanner Jdbc drivers as well ? I am not seeing anything from the driver documentation.
https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc/
Has anyone faced similar issues before,Any help greatly appreciated .
Read through the documenation on Google for Spanner driver , it does not explicity mention this option.
The option is mentioned in google client library pages,
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/leader-aware-routing

TLDR: The leaderAwareRouting option is enabled by default, so you don't have to configure anything for it.
Longer Version
The Spanner JDBC driver is built on top of the Spanner Java client library, and therefore contains all the same features as the client library. Options however need to be configured through the JDBC connection URL. There is no option for leaderAwareRouting in the JDBC connection URL for the Spanner JDBC driver, because the option is enabled by default, and there is no real use case where you would want to disable this feature.
The feature is relatively new, so you should make sure that you use the newest version of the Spanner JDBC driver.
If you still think something is wrong, then try to create a small test application that executes the same transaction using both the Java client library and the JDBC driver. If you see a significant difference in the execution time, then you should open an issue in the JDBC GitHub repository and share the code for your test app there.

Thanks  Knut  , for the response . We are upgrading the spanner jdbc driver  to the latest version  2.20.1 to check if this helps to resolve the latency.
